# Implement adding an image from gallery to favourites, which is displayed on a separate page// DJANGO/JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, django

Essentially I am creating a web gallery with Django/JS for a project, however the project needs to feature CRUD functionality. Currently I have a functioning modal when an image in the gallary is clicked, along with an "Add to Favourites" button when the user is logged in. I am struggling to come up with a way to append these images dynamically to the favourites HTML page. I am unsure whether this is easier done with JS or Django.

Here is my current JS code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.myImg').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            $('#myModal').css('display', 'block')
            $('#imgModal').attr('src', this.src)
            $('.navbar').css('display', 'none')
        })
        /* Favourite image functionality */
        var favouriteImages = []
        
        imgSrc = $(this).attr('src', this.src);
        $('#favourites-btn').click(function () {
            favouriteImages.push(imgSrc)
        })
    })
    $('.close').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            $('#myModal').css('display', 'none')
            $('.navbar').css('display', 'flex')
        })
    })
})

favouriteImages.forEach(function() {
    $('#favourites-gal').append(<img class='myImg'/>)
})
```

**At the bottom, with the favouriteImages.forEach function, I dont know how to include the src of the specific image that is being appended after clicking the Add to Favorites button.**

For reference: In the actual gallary of images the code structure of the HTML is:

```
<div class="gal">
                <img class="myImg" src="{% static 'img/artsy-gallery/artsy1.webp' %}" alt="">

                <img class="myImg" src="{% static 'img/artsy-gallery/artsy2.webp' %}" alt="">

                <img class="myImg" src="{% static 'img/artsy-gallery/artsy3.webp' %}" alt="">

                <img class="myImg" src="{% static 'img/artsy-gallery/artsy4.webp' %}" alt="">



                <img class="myImg" src="{% static 'img/artsy-gallery/artsy5.webp' %}" alt="">
                <img class="myImg" src="{% static 'img/artsy-gallery/artsy6.webp' %}" alt="">
                <img class="myImg" src="{% static 'img/artsy-gallery/artsy7.webp' %}" alt="">
                <img class="myImg" src="{% static 'img/artsy-gallery/artsy8.webp' %}" alt="">

                <img class="myImg" src="{% static 'img/artsy-gallery/artsy9.webp' %}" alt="">

                <img class="myImg" src="{% static 'img/artsy-gallery/artsy10.webp' %}" alt="">

                <img class="myImg" src="{% static 'img/artsy-gallery/artsy11.webp' %}" alt="">
                <img class="myImg" src="{% static 'img/artsy-gallery/artsy12.webp' %}" alt="">
                <img class="myImg" src="{% static 'img/artsy-gallery/artsy13.webp' %}" alt="">
            </div>
```

The favourites gallary will follow the same structure, only this time the images will be appended to the gal div, dynamically, after being added by the user to their favourites using the "Add to favourites button.

INCASE THIS INFORMATION IS NEEDED THIS IS THE HTML STRUCTURE OF THE MODAL THAT CONTAINS THE FAVOURITES BUTTON:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal text-center" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <img class="modal-content" id="imgModal">
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <button id="favourites-btn" class="uppercase btn btn-primary overlay-btn">Add to Favourites</button>
        {% endif %}
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
</div>
```

I am quite lost in what to attempt, and am not sure if I am using the appropriate technology for this, it feels a little overly complicated and am unsure if this could just be accomplished easier by purely using Django.

Comment: If i understand correctly, what you are trying to do is create a 'Favourites' page, where the user can see all their own liked/favourite images?

Comment: Correct, users are going to be able to click on images from the gallery of the photographers website and add them to a favourites page when they are logged in. (I know the feature seems redundant for a photography portfolio however my project just requires me to implement CRUD elements, to which this seems like the only real option on a Photography portfolio page) for reference here is the whole page, https://molnar-m-photo.herokuapp.com/

Comment: I think it would be better to implement Django, and to add the images to the user as a foreign key (one-to-many). This way you can add multiple id's (of the images) to a user.
Then, if you visit your own favorites page, just read out all connected image id's and display(?) them. Alternatively, you can also use a link ref to the image using the id.

Though this would only be possible if the images uploaded have an id.
So the foreign key class 'Image' or whatever has a relation to the user.
And a user can have multiple images connected to them.

Comment: Though my answer is just my opnion, which may be wrong entirely, i think that that would be the easiest and most efficient way to go about it.